# How to disable Google compute enger VM manager?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I accidentally enable the VM manager in GCE and I found no way to disable it,
is there any way to disable it?

Comment: There's no issue if you enabled Compute Engine API. You won't be charged until you run some VMs (except free tire VMs). If you still want to disable it you can go to `APIs & Services` -> click on `Compute Engine API` in the list -> press `DISABLE API`.

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable **OS Config service API** for the project. It will disable the VM Manager.

```
gcloud services disable osconfig.googleapis.com --force
```

**--force** flag is used if there are enabled services which depend on this service will also get disabled.